# Django autocomplete light

Tags: django, django-models, autocomplete, django-forms, django-views

model.py:

```
class Reservation(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(GuestContact, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

class GuestContact(models.Model):
    company = models.CharField(max_lenght=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_lenght=30)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_lenght=30)
```

form.py.

```
class ReservationForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Reservation
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'company': autocomplete.ModelSelect2()
    }
```

views.py

```
class GuestContactAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    def get_queryset(self):

        qs = GuestContact.objects.all()

        if self.q:
            qs = qs.filter(name__istartswith=self.q)

        return qs
```

How i can add to autocomplete queryset only not empty "company" field ?
Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Your company field is required, so I don't think that you will have empty values. Anyways, you can accomplish what you want to do by this:

`GuestContact.objects.exclude(company__isnull=True).exclude(company__exact='')`

Basically, what it does is to exclude `null` and `''` values from the querset.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try `return qs.exclude(company='').exclude(company__isnull=True)` instead of `return qs`.

What's more, you probably wanted `qs = qs.filter(company__istartswith=self.q)` instead of `qs = qs.filter(name__istartswith=self.q)` (based on `forms.py`)

so I think that your `views.py` code should be:

```
class GuestContactAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    def get_queryset(self):

        qs = GuestContact.objects.all()

        if self.q:
            qs = qs.filter(company__istartswith=self.q)

        return qs.exclude(company='').exclude(company__isnull=True)
```